# Including Success / Fail to jQuery / Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I used http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ to help me build a jQuery function to Add An Item to a shopping cart.

My result is this and it works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// Attach a submit handler to the form
$('form[name="cart_quantity"]').submit(function( event ) {

// Stop form from submitting normally and initiate function
event.preventDefault();
return addtocart(jQuery(this));

}); // eof Attach a submit handler to the form

// function
function addtocart(thisForm) {

// Get some values from elements on the page:
$("#contentss").fadeIn("slow");
action = thisForm.attr("action");

// Send the data using post
var posting = $.post( action, thisForm.serialize());

// Process post-results
posting.done(function(data) {

// find and put results in a div
var shoppingCartSidebox = $(data).find('div#shoppingcart').html();
var numbernotify = $(data).find('div.numbernotify').html();
$('div#shoppingcartdiv').html(shoppingCartSidebox);
$('div.numbernotify').html(numbernotify)

// initiate slideDown / slideUp
$(document.getElementById('contentss').style.display='none');
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#shoppingcartdiv").slideDown();
setTimeout(function() {$("#shoppingcartdiv").slideUp()}, 7000);

}); // eof initiate slideDown / slideUp document ready
}); // eof Process post-results
} // eof function
}); // eof main document ready
```

I would like to implement Success / Fail events in the instant that the product does not get added to the cart. The success event is already coded and is basically defined by the events followed by "// Process post-results"

So I need to insert a Fail event that would contain a similar outcome to the Success, but of course instead of alerting the user that the item has been added successfully, it would warn them that an error occurred. However I just want to ask as well, would adding in a Fail event initiate in the case, for example, a user loses his internet connection while adding the item to their cart? Because that's what I'm looking for essentially...

Also, I think it's quite noticeable that I'm a terrible amateur so any advice on the current code and improvement would be highly appreciated.

Comment: like posting.done(function(data){}); you can also do posting.fail(function(data){//to do when it fails}); posting.always(function(data){to do always, regardless of success or failure});

Comment: Great :D .. good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery ajax Callback functions

More on it :http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
alert( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" ); // if something goes wrong
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" ); // will always be executed, regardless of success or failure
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Aman's code in the comments worked and his follow-up answer seems like the simpler solution and more formal solution - but for anyone else that's going to use my amateur code, here is the end result based on Aman's comments:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

// Attach a submit handler to the form
$('form[name="cart_quantity"]').submit(function( event ) {

// Stop form from submitting normally and initiate function
event.preventDefault();
return addtocart(jQuery(this));

}); // eof Attach a submit handler to the form

// function
function addtocart(thisForm) {

// Get some values from elements on the page:
$("#contentss").fadeIn("slow");
action = thisForm.attr("action");

// Send the data using post
var posting = $.post( action, thisForm.serialize());

// Process post-results request Success
posting.done(function(data) {

// find and put results in a div
var shoppingCartSidebox = $(data).find('div#shoppingcart').html();
var numbernotify = $(data).find('div.numbernotify').html();
$('div#shoppingcartdiv').html(shoppingCartSidebox);
$('div.numbernotify').html(numbernotify)

// initiate slideDown / slideUp
$(document.getElementById('contentss').style.display='none');
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#shoppingcartdiv").slideDown();
setTimeout(function() {$("#shoppingcartdiv").slideUp()}, 7000);

}); // eof initiate slideDown / slideUp document ready
}); // eof Process post-results

// Process post-results request Fail
posting.fail(function(data){
$(document.getElementById('contentss').style.display='none');
alert ("Failed");
}); // eof Process post-results request Fail

// Process post-results request Success & Fail
posting.always(function(data){
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
}); // eof Process post-results request Success & Fail

} // eof function
}); // eof main document ready
```

The functions I used here in posting.fail and posting.always are of course placeholders for (now) testing - and will end up being a bit more user-friendly for the user in terms of alerting them that something's gone wrong. Also to answer a part of my own initial question, this worked when I pulled the plug on WAMP server and tried to add a product to the cart, so I'm assuming it will work for lost internet connections.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like jQuery's promise implementation (and I'm [not the only one](https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970)). In this case, my reason is this:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php")
.done(function(data) {
  // You can get your data, but...
})
.fail(function() {
  // What is the error? Do I get a code? jQuery docs don't say...
  alert( "error" );
})
```

In general, I prefer to use the long-hand syntax for AJAX requests in jQuery. The `$.post` method is a [shorthand method](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) that supposedly makes things easier for the developer. But it accomplishes this by hiding certain configuration options (which long experience has taught me I almost always need before deploying an app to a real server).

So I prefer the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method, which exposes the very helpful error handlers `error` and `statusCode`. So you can rewrite your code as the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.Form.attr("action"),
    data: this.Form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        // The rest of your success function
        // i.e. from posting.done
    },
    error: function(xhrReq, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // The rest of your error handling code
        // i.e. from posting.fail
        // You can also retry the request or report the specific error
    },
    statusCode: // notice: statusCode singular
    {
        // Plain object syntax with integer status codes as the keys
        403: function() {
            alert("403 Forbidden. You do not have permission for this action.");
        },
        500: function() {
            alert("500 Internal Server Error. Try again later.");
        }
    }
});
```

The docs say this about the `error` handler:

> **error**
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. **Note:** *This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.* This is an Ajax Event.

And this about the `statusCode` handler:

> **statusCode** (default: {})
> Type: PlainObject
> An object of numeric HTTP codes and functions to be called when the response has the corresponding code. For example, the following will alert when the response status is a 404: (see above)
>
> If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; if it results in an error (including 3xx redirect), they take the same parameters as the error callback.

That said, if you have a working solution, by all means go for it. But just keep in mind that if your programming requirements get too much more complicated, the training wheels have to come off.

Comment: Thanks for this. My initial question was going to be that someone help me convert my current code to an $.ajax solution - but I was afraid to ask for seemingly not even trying and thus providing a sample attempt. Truth is I looked at the layout of an $.ajax solution and I had no idea what to do with the URL and Data fields in terms of tying it in with my current code :/ So I just stuck with what I had lol - but you just handed it to me on a silver platter, and I'm definitely going to now use the code you've provided :D Once again, thanks!